# Adding ignore to PaperTrail using has_paper_trail_defaults

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We currently have

```
PaperTrail.config.has_paper_trail_defaults = {
  on: %i(create update destroy)
}
```

but would like to have

```
PaperTrail.config.has_paper_trail_defaults = {
  on: %i(create update destroy),
  ignore: :updated_at
}
```

For some reason the ignore is getting ignored. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `ignore` expects an array (or a hash argument)

try...

```
ignore: [:updated_at]
```

Note that `updated_at` will still appear in a version record that was created for some other reason.  If you never want it to appear in the version record, use `skip`

```
skip: [:updated_at]
```